# Is WIndows 7 style access to grouped windows possible in Ubuntu 12.04 unity 2d?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d, interface

Selecting grouped windows with a mouse is highly inconvenient. Let's say I have two firefox windows open and I want to select one of the two with a mouse. I have to click on the firefox launcher then possibly move the mouse across the screen by a distance, depending on how many instances are open and which one I want to access, then click on that. In Windows 7, thumbnail views of the open windows are shown right next to the launcher, which is way more convenient. I am even fine with if only some text, instead of thumbnails, are displayed next to the launcher.

Comment: Unity launcher can't do that. Only possible solution I know is `dockbarx` which isn't available for 12.04